# How to get the default InputDecorationTheme.fillColor in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my custom form field, I would like to get app's default fillColor and use it in my custom control. What is the right way to do it? The following approach returns null, even though the default TextFormField fills with a shade of grey.

```
class CustomFormField extends FormField<String> {
  CustomFormField({
    String? initialText,
    FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<String>? validator,
    AutovalidateMode? autovalidateMode,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(
          onSaved: onSaved,
          validator: validator,
          initialValue: initialText,
          autovalidateMode: autovalidateMode,
          key: key,
          builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
            var fillColor =
                Theme.of(state.context).inputDecorationTheme.fillColor;
            // ISSUE: fillColor is null, even though the default 
            // TextFormField fills with a shade of grey in the same app. 
            return Container(
                // with custom control UI using fillColor
                );
          },
        );
}
```

Comment: can you include more context about your `builder`

Comment: It is a standard custom field implementation. Added more code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by explicitly setting the inputDecorationTheme at the app-level when the app is initialized.

```
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    ...
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
    ),
    ...
  ),
);
```